# How do I get a field translated in Drupal 8

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n, 8

I have a multilingual site in Drupal 8, and several node, some translated and others not.
As I can programmatically get the translated field or by default they give it back from the original language.

I got this:

```
$service_entities = entity_load_multiple_by_properties('node', array('type' => 'service'));

$services = [];
foreach ($service_entities as $entity) {
  $services[] = [
    'title' => $entity->title->value,
  ];
}
```

This code work fine, but when the title is translated Drupal give back in the default language in which it was created.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can get a specific translation with `$translation = $entity->getTranslation('de')`, then you can use $translation exactly the same as $entity.

Usually, you don't want to get a specific translation, but the best translation that is available for the current language. For that, use getTranslationFromContext() like this:

```
 $translation = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($entity);
```

Comment: @Bedir the last code(`getTranslationFromContext`) when I'm logged translations work well, but when I logout not working, you know why this happens?

Comment: `entityManager` is deprecated. use `\Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($entity);` instead

Comment: This is not working giving me undefined error. Can you paste the latest code.

Comment: @PhilippMichael – Updated answer.

Comment: And `$translation->getTitle()` will return the translated version then ?

Answer (score 5):

Loading all help_page and return it in the current language:

```
$elements = [];
$ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'help_page')
  ->execute();
$nodes = Node::loadMultiple($ids);
$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $translation = $node->getTranslation($language);
  $elements[] = [
    'title' => $translation->title->value,
    'url' => $translation->url(),
    'img' => $translation->field_imagen->entity->url(),
    'text' => $translation->body->value,
  ];
}
return $elements;
```