# is getString() returning translated content?

Tags: 8

```
$links['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['attributes']['title'] = 

$entity->field_anc_label->getString();
```

I am using getString() value , need to know whether its translated or we need to call it under t() to get it translated ?

Comment: Only if you get a translation of the entity first, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145744/how-do-i-get-a-field-translated-in-drupal-8

Answer (score 1):

you can check translation with something like

```
if ($entity->get('field_anc_label')->getFieldDefinition()->isTranslatable()) {
  // The field translation is enabled.
$links['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['attributes']['title'] = $entity->field_anc_label->getString();
}else{
$links['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['attributes']['title'] = 
t($entity->field_anc_label->getString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

t() is for translation of string literals in UI. To translate content you have to use [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/entity-translation-api).

In this case for example:

```
$translated_entity = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')
  ->getTranslationFromCon‌​text($entity);

$links['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['attributes']['title'] = 
  $translated_entity->field_anc_label->value;
```